# Why is C# tuple notation not available for 1-tuples?

Tags: c#, tuples, valuetuple

Why is the easy tuple declaration syntax (int, double) t1 = (17, 3.14); not available for 1-tuple ?

CS8124 : Tuple must contain at least two elements seems odd when ValueTuple exists, isnt it ?

```
public class MyDict : Dictionary<(int a, int b), int> // ok
{
    public MyDict()
    {
        Add(new ValueTuple<int, int>(1, 2), 0);
    }
}

public class MyDict2 : Dictionary<(int a), int>  // Error CS8124 : Tuple must contain at least two elements.
{
}

public class MyDict3 : Dictionary<ValueTuple<int, int>, int> // ok
{
    public MyDict3()
    {
        Add((1, 2), 0);
    }
}

public class MyDict4 : Dictionary<ValueTuple<int>, int> // ok
{
    public MyDict4()
    {
        Add((1), 0); // Argument of type int is not assignable to parameter type System.ValueTuple<int>  
        Add(ValueTuple.Create(1), 0); // ok
    }
}
```

Comment: My guess would be that it would create ambiguous syntax. (Ignoring the reasoning on _why you would even want that_.)

Comment: Why would you need a tuple for a single value?

Comment: See Marc Gravell's answer in the dupe target. This would break existing code.

Comment: @phuzi See https://stackoverflow.com/q/51722973/5133585

Comment: @Sweeper Quote from the accepted answer "A 1-tuple is not very useful since it could easily be replaced with a single int."

Comment: In short - because it was designed this way and specification [is explicit about it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/types#8311-tuple-types): _"A tuple type is written `(T1 I1, ..., Tn In)` with `n ≥ 2`, where the identifiers I1...In are optional tuple element names."_

Comment: @Phuzi Having a named tuple as a T key of a dictionary without having to define an entire record for two poor getters while still expressing intent on what the key represents would be nice. Dictionnary keys may be a single value so that would make a 1-tuple in this case.